# Squaring wood with limited available tools

Tags: furniture, hand-tools, tool-selection

Living in an isolated neck of the woods and need to square some planks for a table project. Don't have a bench, or a table saw. Have a rip saw a straight edge and limited power tools (Jig saw and a belt sander). Any tips for getting a straight edge other than draging it along the highway? Cheers

Comment: You are looking to put these boards together so you can make a table top with them? Do you have a work bench, clamps, planes or other tools. I would like to know why the edge needs to be straight first. This might not be the project for you to start on.... A picture of what wood you are working with and/or a facsimile of your project plan could be helpful here.

Comment: I am not as concerned about a perfect join for the table top as it will be a rough finish. The main reason for the strait edge is the planks will also make up the sides and shelves that will form the base/ legs of the table and need to be square so the thing stands straight. And no I don't have a work bench, clamps planes or other tools that would make it easier.

Comment: Handplanes (jointing plane in particular, and a shooting board for the end-grain)) would be the traditional tool for making a board square and flat. But it sounds more like you're askinb how to make a case square. A sketch of whst you're trying to buils and what you'remost concerned about would help.

Comment: Are you just describing something like this? http://www.yucatancustomfurniture.com/site/assets/files/5916/simple_rustic_coffee_table.700x0.png

Comment: Are you only looking for hand tools answers? You mention powertools but only tagged hand

Comment: I suppose you could hack together some shooting board esque thing with the belt sander but hand planes and a straight edge are the way to go. Use the straightedge to find humps, mark with pencil, shave with handplane, repeat until satisfactory.

Comment: Although... what grit is your highway?

Comment: Most highways in my experience run at about a #2 to maybe a #4 grit. I would not recommend it since the abrasive grit is not screened very well

Comment: Are you asking how to square the wood with only the tools you have, or are you asking for recommendations on the minimal tools required to square up the wood?

Answer (score 2):

Since your tool selection is so limited, your best chance to get a straight edge will be with your primary cutting tool, the rip saw. You do not mention if the saw is a hand saw or power saw, which really will not matter, since it will have everything to do with how YOU control the tool and what kind of inconsistencies you can live with when the cuts are done.

Rip saws are for cutting with (lengthwise) the grain of the wood although they can cut across the grain too.

Your biggest issue will be to cut the line square and mark it so you can follow the line accurately. A power tool usually will have the blade set so  the cut will be set at 90 degree in one direction, the depth of cut or thickness. The other direction along the face, or width, is up to you as I mentioned before. When using a hand tool, all squareness, in both directions is under your control.

A little sketch of what you want to build will help too. Knowing how each cut works to build the table can give insight on some shortcuts for using limited tools.

Comment: Correction: ripping is cutting along the grain and crosscutting is cutting across the grain.

Comment: Absolutely correct, my bad, I will correct the post. Momentary lapse of reason....

Comment: I will be getting my hands on a plane of sorts. Thanks for all the insight. Cheers

Comment: If you can rip both boards at once by stacking them on top of each other the squareness is less important. If you decide on being less perfect and allow this in your design it is also easier.